# Integration using trapezium method SciPy problems ('numpy.ndarray' object is not callable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, integrate

I'm trying to create a function that lets you input an expression for y with upper and lower bounds and N number of steps. It takes the expression, should integrate it and then run it through the trapezium method for N steps and spit out the result. Currently there is an error ('numpy.ndarray' object is not callable) in my way. Not sure how to fix it! Here's the code!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
%matplotlib inline

def trap(f,b,a):
        return 0.5 * (b-a)*(f(a) + f(b))
def multistep(f,method,b,a,N):
    step = (b-a)/N
    lower = np.linspace(b,a,N,endpoint=False)
    upper = np.linspace(b+step,a,N)
    result = 0
    for n in range(N):
        result += method(f,lower[n],upper[n])
    return result

def trapezium_rule_integration_function(f,a,b,N):
    x = np.linspace(b,a,N)
    yf = []
    for p in x:
        yf.append(f(p))
    y = np.array(yf)
    return multistep(y,trap,b,a,N)
y = 1/(1+x**2)
trapezium_rule_integration_function(y,10,0,100)
```

Thank you in advance for any support available.

Johann Brahms

Answer (score 0):

By looking quickly, I see that this error stems from the function trapezium_rule_integration_function,

```
y = np.array(yf)
return multistep(y,trap,b,a,N)
```

The first argument of multistep should be a function, but you provided an array y, which is not callable by '()'. This array is then passed to multistep, which expects a function f instead.

By the way, you should rewrite y as

```
y = lambda x: 1/(1+x**2)
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a massive help!!